# gdal and ERROR 4

Tags: gdal

When I use gdalinfo to list information about a geotiff image and the current path is a USB flash drive, It is ok and correctly shows information. But when I copy data from flash memory to HDD and use gdalinfo at new path, it shows this error:

> ERROR 4: 'dataxxxxx.tif' not recognised as a supported file format.

What could be causing this problem?
OS is CentOS 7.

Comment: Quite impossible to say. Error means that file exists (otherwise you would see ERROR 4: foo.tif: No such file or directory) but somehow it is no more a valid image file. I bet that you can't open the copied image with image viewers either.

Answer (score 1):

Check your file with [file](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file) and [identify](https://linux.die.net/man/1/identify).

Sample outputs:

```
# file image.tif 
image.tif: TIFF image data, little-endian, direntries=17, height=712, bps=218, compression=none, PhotometricIntepretation=RGB, width=758
```

and :

```
# identify image.tif 
image.tif TIFF 758x712 758x712+0+0 8-bit sRGB 1.621MB 0.010u 0:00.009
```

If both failed to identify your tif, then your file should be corrupted.
You can then open it with an hexadecimal editor to check.